# how to append a Tuple2 to an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala

is there any problem in my scala code ?

```
val arr = new ArrayBuffer[Tuple2]
val t = (1, 2)
arr.append(t)
```

I think my code is correct, but the compiler says:

```
type mismatch, expected:Tuple2, actual:(int, int)
```

I wonder what is the difference between `Tuple2` and `(int, int)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tuple2` is a type constructor. You want `Tuple2[Int, Int]` instead.